# How to communicate between components and slots?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'd like to know if it's possible to have a component communicate with a v-model within a slot?

```
<medical-form>
    <input type="text" v-model="dob" />
</medical-form>
```

In this example the **dob** data is defined in the `medical-form` component. The contents of the slot are generated server side as it uses sensitive information to work out which fields should be presented, because of this I can't fully move the form into the `medical-form` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can give `slot-scope` and you will get the data

In your `medical-form component` `bind` your dynamic value.

`<slot :dob="dob" />`

```
<medical-form>
    <template slot-scope="{dob}">
     <input type="text" v-model="dob" />
    </slot>
</medical-form>
```

But recently `vue` deprecated using of `slot-scope` but it is backward compatible and will work. However I would like to show you that also.

Reference - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

```
<medical-form>
  <template v-slot="{dob}">
    <input type="text" v-model="dob" />
  </template>
</medical-form>
```